# Hide search box on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a search box, and a button.  I want to slide the search box up and off screen to make a nice sliding effect for hiding/showing the search box when someone clicks the button.  Is there a way to do this smoothly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the UIView animations and change the frame origin of serachbar from 0 to -44 in the animation block and your job is done.